# Is it possible to save year 1 to 99 as date-value in Access database?

Tags: ms-access, date

Access automatically converts any value under 100. ie: 0099 converts to 1999 and 0010 to 2010 and 0001 to 2001.

Is there any way around this problem or is it not possible to save dates in Access so far away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access won't let you store dates earlier than [1/1/100 AD](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210276).

Of course, you could always just store an integer for the year and do your own date handling.

Comment: Many other database engines have much worse restrictions on the date range.